# Cannot get local javascript file to execute when web view loads a remote page

Tags: javascript, ios6, xcode4.5

I have worked on this for several days and do not know what I am doing wrong.
Any help is appreciated

1. I have set the delegate.
2. I have moved the javascript file to the Copy Bundle.
3. See code below.

   ```
   - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView 
   {

   NSString *jsPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"doc" ofType:@"js" inDirectory:NO];

   NSString *js = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:jsPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

   [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];

    }
   ```

My javascript file looks like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
alert("hello");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the script tag from the JavaScript and it will work